# Emails via script get set out 3 times?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a email script that runs every 15 minutes and is supposed to send a email once using PHP mailer. For some reason, it's sending out 3 emails a time.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

// Database connect

include("class.phpmailer.php");

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM eblast_email WHERE id = '1'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

$get_event_id = "".$myrow2['event_id']."";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Login information here

$mail->Subject = "Subject here";

$html.= "HTML Message here";

$plain = "Plain Message here";

$mail->Body = $html;
$mail->AltBody = $plain;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM email_users WHERE sent = 'no' LIMIT 0, 40";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$email_to_send_to = "".$myrow['email']."";

$rsvp_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event_members WHERE event_attending='$get_event_id' AND email='$email_to_send_to'");
$rsvp_check_done = mysql_num_rows($rsvp_check);

if ($rsvp_check_done == 0) {
$mail->AddAddress($email_to_send_to);
if(!$mail->Send()) {

echo "<b>Error sending email to " . $myrow['email'] . ". </b>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
echo "<br>";
} else {
echo "Message to " . $myrow['email'] . " has been sent.<br>";
}
mysql_query("UPDATE email_users SET sent='yes' WHERE email='".$myrow['email']."'") or die (mysql_error());
$mail->ClearAddresses();

} else {
mysql_query("UPDATE email_users SET sent='yes' WHERE email='$email_to_send_to'") or die (mysql_error());
echo "$email_to_send_to has already registered ($rsvp_check_done) -- $get_event_id && $email_to_send_to<br>";
}

sleep(2);

}


}
echo "<br>Done.";

?>
```

Comment: You invoke `$mail->Send()` only once, maybe the script itself is called three times? Or there is something wrong within the class?

Comment: Try to execute the script manually and see if your problem still occurs. Also, it is a good idea to fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: I can't really run it right now. Don't want to send a test email to 900 users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code to have write to a log file every time it runs. My guess is that it's just getting called 3 times.

Example:

```
file_put_contents("log.txt", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Ok! This could be the case because I have moved this site over from many different servers so I could have cron jobs running in different places! I'll add this and see was comes out.